# Google File Picker + drive.file

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, google-picker

As part of Project Strobe, Google is planning to move many of the Google Drive API scopes to "restricted" which means that you need an independent security verification.

In the same article, they suggest using the Google Picker and drive.file scope to obtain per file access. I've successfully implemented the Google Picker API to access files and retreive the meta data of the file. But how do I actually import the content of the file with this flow (for example, the data in an actual Google sheet)?

**GOOGLE PICKER WRAPPER**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import loadScript from "load-script";

const GOOGLE_SDK_URL = "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js";

let scriptLoadingStarted = false;

class GoogleFilePicker extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    clientId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    developerKey: PropTypes.string,
    scope: PropTypes.array,
    viewId: PropTypes.string,
    authImmediate: PropTypes.bool,
    origin: PropTypes.string,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    onAuthenticate: PropTypes.func,
    onAuthFailed: PropTypes.func,
    createPicker: PropTypes.func,
    multiselect: PropTypes.bool,
    navHidden: PropTypes.bool,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    authToken: PropTypes.string,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    onChange: () => {},
    onAuthenticate: () => {},
    onAuthFailed: () => {},
    scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"],
    viewId: "DOCS",
    authImmediate: false,
    multiselect: false,
    navHidden: false,
    disabled: false,
    authToken: "",
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onApiLoad = this.onApiLoad.bind(this);
    this.onChoose = this.onChoose.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.isGoogleReady()) {
      // google api is already exists
      // init immediately
      this.onApiLoad();
    } else if (!scriptLoadingStarted) {
      // load google api and the init
      scriptLoadingStarted = true;
      loadScript(GOOGLE_SDK_URL, this.onApiLoad);
    } else {
      // is loading
    }
  }

  isGoogleReady() {
    return !!window.gapi;
  }

  isGoogleAuthReady() {
    return !!window.gapi.auth;
  }

  isGooglePickerReady() {
    return !!window.google.picker;
  }

  onApiLoad() {
    window.gapi.load("auth");
    window.gapi.load("picker");
  }

  doAuth(callback) {
    window.gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        client_id: this.props.clientId,
        scope: this.props.scope,
        immediate: this.props.authImmediate,
      },
      callback
    );
  }

  onChoose() {
    if (
      !this.isGoogleReady() ||
      !this.isGoogleAuthReady() ||
      !this.isGooglePickerReady() ||
      this.props.disabled
    ) {
      return null;
    }

    // const token = window.gapi.auth.getToken();
    // const oauthToken = token && token.access_token;
    const oauthToken = this.props.authToken;

    if (oauthToken) {
      this.createPicker(oauthToken);
    } else {
      this.doAuth((response) => {
        if (response.access_token) {
          this.createPicker(response.access_token);
        } else {
          this.props.onAuthFailed(response);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  createPicker(oauthToken) {
    // this.props.onAuthenticate(oauthToken);

    if (this.props.createPicker) {
      return this.props.createPicker(window.google, oauthToken);
    }

    const googleViewId = window.google.picker.ViewId[this.props.viewId];
    const view = new window.google.picker.View(googleViewId);

    if (this.props.mimeTypes) {
      view.setMimeTypes(this.props.mimeTypes.join(","));
    }
    if (this.props.query) {
      view.setQuery(this.props.query);
    }

    if (!view) {
      throw new Error("Can't find view by viewId");
    }

    const picker = new window.google.picker.PickerBuilder()
      .addView(view)
      .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
      .setDeveloperKey(this.props.developerKey)
      .setCallback(this.props.onChange);

    if (this.props.origin) {
      picker.setOrigin(this.props.origin);
    }

    if (this.props.navHidden) {
      picker.enableFeature(window.google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN);
    }

    if (this.props.multiselect) {
      picker.enableFeature(window.google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED);
    }

    picker.build().setVisible(true);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(window.gapi);
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onChoose}>
        {this.props.children ? (
          this.props.children
        ) : (
          <button>Open google chooser</button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleFilePicker;
```

**CALLING THE WRAPPER**

I'm calling the component above in the code below. Once the document is retrieved I call the copyFile function. This function works as expected when the document has been created by the app, but not when the file has been created by the user outside of the app. I know that this intended by Google for the drive.google.file scope but the documentation implies that using the Google Picker should solve this. Can you please clarify?

```
  <GoogleFilePicker
    clientId="CLIENT ID"
    developerKey="DEVELOPER KEY"
    scope={["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"]}
    onChange={(data) => {
      if (data.docs) {
        copyFile(data.docs[0].id, `Template: ${data.docs[0].name}`, "");
      }
    }}
    onAuthenticate={(token) => console.log("oauth token:", token)}
    onAuthFailed={(data) => console.log("on auth failed:", data)}
    multiselect={true}
    navHidden={true}
    authImmediate={false}
    // mimeTypes={["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg"]}
    viewId={"DOCS"}
    authToken={auth.state.user.googleToken}
  >
```

Comment: Hi ! Do you get any error message when you try to copy a file not created in your application? [copyFile](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy) will only create a copy of the file in your application folder, not get you the content data. Is ```copyFile``` working successfully? Does it create an actual copy of your file? If you are more interested in just retrieving the data take a look at the method [get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get).

Comment: Yes, I get an error saying the file is not found. I'm grabbing the file ID using the google picker and the attempting to copy it into my application folder on the backend using the Google Drive File Api. Do you mean I should use get on the front end?

Comment: Hi ! No, you can perfectly do everything on the front-end. After taking a closer look, I have realised that you are not implementing the method for copying the file in the callback as you should. If you [check and follow the documentation example](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs#implement-the-picker-callback) you will see that it is in the **callback** function in your picker wrapper instead of in the ```<GoogleFilePicker>``` tag where you should implement your method for copying the file. Try that and let me know how it goes for debugging the rest of possible issues :D